# $K_n$ as an union of bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Theorem: The complete graph $K_n$ can be expressed as the union of $k$ bipartite graphs if and only if $n \leq 2^k.$

I would appreciate a pedagogical explanation of the theorem. Graph Theory by West gives the proof but I don't understand it. Also this [referece](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=ButlynVk25MC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=complete+graph+union+of+bipartite+graphs&source=bl&ots=u5hnHoWU_N&sig=vFY8SIHy4OH8O683FyPtJk4o8-M&hl=es&sa=X&ei=nr2RVaCrKov3oASojoL4Aw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=complete%20graph%20union%20of%20bipartite%20graphs&f=false) has the proof, but it kills me with the dyadic expansion argument.

Also, I don't see why $n \leq 2^k$, since the complete graph I can make it from the union of disjoint $K_{1,1}$ bipartite graphs, for instance. I just need $n(n-1)/2$ of such $K_{1,1}$.

Comment: Example: Look at $K_4$. Your proposed method would require $6$ copies of the $K_{1, 1}$ graph, but what if we wanted to express it as $k = 2$ bipartite graphs? My point here is that $k$ isn't fixed; your decomposition isn't always the right size. The theorem says we *can* decompose it into $k = 2$ bipartite graphs, because $4 = n \le 2^k = 2^2 = 4$, but your decomposition doesn't always give us what we want (although it will work for a particular $k$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you’re taking $k=\frac12n(n-1)$. For this $k$ it’s certainly true that $n\le 2^k$; in fact, if $n\ge 3$, $\frac12n(n-1)\ge n$, so $2^k\ge 2^n>n$. Thus, your example is entirely consistent with the result in question.

The point of the theorem is that (1) if $n\le 2^k$, then you *can* cover $K_n$ with $k$ bipartite graphs, but (2) if $n>2^k$, then you *cannot* do so. Since it’s $n$ that’s known and $k$ that we’re interested in, it might be more intuitive to solve these inequalities for $k$ in terms of $n$:

- if $k\ge\lceil\log_2n\rceil$, then you *can* cover $K_n$ with $k$ bipartite graphs, but
- if $k<\lceil\log_2n\rceil$, then you *cannot*.

In other words, $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ is the smallest number of bipartite graphs that are sufficient to cover $K_n$: no smaller number will do the trick.

The proof in Bollobás’s book is more straightforward than it probably looks; I’ll just expand it with a bit of extra explanation. The first point is that if $k$ bipartite graphs are enough to cover $K_{2^k}$, then $k$ bipartite graphs are enough to cover $K_n$ for any $n\le 2^k$. To see this, just note that if $n\le 2^k$, then $K_n$ is a subgraph of $K_{2^k}$, so any covering of $K_{2^k}$ by bipartite graphs automatically yields one of $K_n$ as well.

Now label the $2^k$ vertices of $K_{2^k}$ with the $2^k$ possible sequences of $k$ zeroes and ones.

> For example, if $k=3$, the $2^3=8$ vertices are labelled $000,001,010,011,100,101,110$, and $111$. These strings are just the binary (base two) representations of the integers $0,1,\ldots,7$, padded where necessary with leading zeroes to make their lengths uniformly $3$.

Thus, if the vertices are $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{2^k-1}$, we label vertex $v_i$ with the $k$-digit binary representation of the integer $i$; we can write that string $b_1^{(i)}b_2^{(i)}\ldots b_k^{(i)}$.

> In the $k=3$ example, $v_5$ is labelled $101$, so $b_1^{(5)}=1$, $b_2^{(5)}=0$, and $b_3^{(5)}=1$.

Now let $\ell$ be any index between $1$ and $k$ inclusive. Let

$$U_\ell=\left\{v_i:b_\ell^{(i)}=0\right\}\;,$$

the set of vertices whose labels have a $0$ in position $\ell$, and let

$$V_\ell=\left\{v_i:b_\ell^{(i)}=1\right\}\,$$

the set of vertices whose labels have a $1$ in position $\ell$. Clearly these two sets of vertices are disjoint. Let $G_\ell$ be the complete bipartite graph whose parts are the sets $U_\ell$ and $V_\ell$: the vertex set of $G_\ell$ is $U_\ell\cup V_\ell$, and the edges of $G_\ell$ are all of the pairs $\{u,v\}$ with $u\in U_\ell$ and $v\in V_\ell$.

$G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_k$ are then $k$ bipartite subgraphs of $K_{2^k}$, and I claim that they cover $K_{2^k}$. To see this, let $v_i$ and $v_j$ be any two distinct vertices of $K_{2^k}$. Then $v_i$ and $v_j$ have different labels $b_1^{(i)}b_2^{(i)}\ldots b_k^{(i)}$ and $b_1^{(j)}b_2^{(j)}\ldots b_k^{(j)}$. Since the labels are different, there must be an index $\ell$ such that $b_\ell^{(i)}\ne b_\ell^{(j)}$. Thus one of $v_i$ and $v_j$ is in $U_\ell$, the other is in $V_\ell$, and the edge $\{v_i,v_j\}$ of $K_{2^k}$ is in $G_\ell$.

This shows the first bullet point above. To show the second bullet point, it’s enough to show that $K_{2^k+1}$ cannot be covered by $k$ bipartite graphs for any $k\ge 0$. Suppose that this is false, and let $k$ be the smallest non-negative integers such that $K_{2^k+1}$ *can* be covered by $k$ bipartite graphs; we want to derive a contradiction. For future reference note that $K_{2^0+1}=K_2$ cannot be covered by $0$ bipartite graphs, so $k>0$.

Let $G_1,\ldots,G_k$ be bipartite graphs covering $K_{2^k+1}$. For $\ell=1,\ldots,k$ let the disjoint vertex sets of $G_\ell$ be $U_\ell$ and $V_\ell$. Note that we may assume that $U_\ell\cup V_\ell$ is the entire vertex set of $K_{2^k+1}$. If not, just throw all of the unused vertices into $U_\ell$: the resulting graph is still bipartite and has exactly the same edges. $2^k+1$ is an odd number, so the $2^k+1$ vertices cannot be split into two sets of the same size: one of the sets $U_k$ and $V_k$ must contain over half of the vertices. Say that $U_k$ does. Then $U_k$ contains at least $2^{k-1}+1$ vertices, and $G_k$ does not contain *any* of the edges between these vertices. This means that all of the edges between these $2^{k-1}+1$ vertices must be covered by the $k-1$ bipartite graphs $G_1,\ldots,G_{k-1}$. In other words, we have a copy of $K_{2^{k-1}+1}$ that is covered by $k-1$ bipartite graphs. But $k$ was chosen to be the *smallest* non-negative integer for which this is possible, so we have our contradiction.

Comment: So the punch line is that any $v_i$ and $v_j$ are always in some bipartite graph and in different partitions. Awesome! I am tempted to ask you if there's an online course to learn graph theory. I am doing a PhD in physics (quantum graphs research) but I really want to learn graphs. I have surveyed through the West book and also the Bondy's "Graph Theory", although this is difficult for me at my stage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2820579: You might take a look at [this site](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/basic.html); if the online text seems readable enough, [this page](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/index.html) has information on getting hard copies. I find this one more readable than West, though both are pretty daunting simply by virtue of the amount of material. (I’ve never actually seen the Bondy; I’m a topologist, not a graph theorist.) I don’t have any familiarity with possibly more elementary books, I’m afraid. You’re welcome!

Comment: HOW 
$$U_\ell=\left\{v_i:b_\ell^{(i)}=0\right\}\;,$$
and 

$$V_\ell=\left\{v_i:b_\ell^{(i)}=1\right\}\,$$

can be written?Isn't this contradictory?
i mean let us take$l$ as $3$ and $i=6$

Now according to your notation $$U_3=\left\{v_6:b_3^{(6)}=0\right\}\;,$$


and  at the same time 


$$V_3=\left\{v_6:b_3^{(6)}=0\right\}\;,$$


is it $$V_\ell=\left\{v_j:b_\ell^{(j)}=1\right\}\,$$
? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @sourav: There is no contradiction. You don’t get to specify $i$. $U_3$ is the set of of $v_i$ that have a $0$ in position $3$, and $V_3$ is the set of $v_i$ that have a $1$ in position $3$.

Comment: if we take the value of $k$=$3$,and if i am doing binary representation of integer $i$=$6$,representation will be $110$

According to your represntation it will be 


  $b_{1}^{\left(6\right)}$ $b_{2}^{\left(6\right)}$ $b_{3}^{\left(6\right)}$


$b_{1}^{\left(6\right)}$=1,
$b_{2}^{\left(6\right)}$=$1$, $b_{3}^{\left(6\right)}$=$0$

Now in your set $U_{l},V_{l}$ you are finding elements on same $i$,$l$

So for any value of $l$=$1,2,3$,Both sets will give same reesult

Example $l=2$

$$U_{2}=\left\{v_6:b_{2}^{(6)}=1\right\}\;,$$
$$V_{2}=\left\{v_6:b_{2}^{(6)}=1\right\}\;,$$

Comment: @sourav: No. If $k=3$, $U_2$ is the set of vertices with labels $000,001,100$, and $101$, and $V_2$ is the set of vertices with labels $010,011,110$, and $111$.

Comment: Okk got it,thanks  a lot ..!!! i think you are making a graph similar to a hypercube !!

Comment: >In other words, we have a copy of $K_{2^{k-1}+1}$ that is covered by $k-1$ bipartite graphs. But $k$ was chosen to be the *smallest* non-negative integer for which this is possible, so we have our contradiction.


In this point i got it that $U_{l}$ has $K_{\frac{2^{k}}{2}+1}$ vertices i.e  

$K_{2^{k-1}+1}$  ,but i am not getting the rest ..please explain sir @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @sourav: I’ll have to get back to you sometime tomorrow: I’m going to be busy or out until then.

Comment: okk sure sir ..!!! no problem   .!!! and thank you for your clarification sir :)

Comment: @sourav: You should only be looking at $U_k$ at this point. $G_k$ is one of the $k$ bipartite graphs covering $K_{2^k+1}$, and $U_k$ is the part of $G_k$ that contains more than half of the $2^k+1$ vertices. Since $\frac12(2^k+1)=2^{k-1}+\frac12$, and $U_k$ certainly must have a whole number of vertices, $U_k$ must contain at least $2^{k-1}+1$ vertices. $U_k$ is a part of the bipartite graph $G_k$, so $G_k$ has no edges between vertices in $U_k$. The whole graph $K_{2^k+1}$, however, *does* have edges between each pair of these $2^{k-1}+1$ vertices. All of these edges must therefore be in ...

Comment: ... one or more of the bipartite graphs $G_1,\ldots,G_{k-1}$. This means that the $k-1$ bipartite graphs $G_1,\ldots,G_{k-1}$ cover the complete graph on the vertices in $U_k$. However, $U_k$ has more than $2^{k-1}$ vertices, so this shows that $K_{2^{k-1}+1}$ can be covered by $k-1$ bipartite graphs. If $M$ is the set of natural numbers $m$ such that $K_{2^m+1}$ can be covered by $m$ bipartite graphs, we’ve just shown that $k-1\in M$. However, back at the beginning of the argument we chose $k$ to be the *smallest* member of $M$, so $k-1\notin M$. This contradiction shows that ...

Comment: ... $M=\varnothing$: there is no natural number $m$ such that $K_{2^m+1}$ can be covered by $m$ bipartite graphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..@BrianM.Scott ...!!!! thank you for always clearing and simplifying my doubt

Comment: @sourav: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

- Proof that $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ bipartite graphs suffices.

  We label the vertices $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.  For $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,\lceil \log_2 n \rceil\}$ we define the $t$-th bipartite graph to contain the complete bipartite graph with vertex bipartition $A \cup B$ with $A$ containing the vertices with $t$-th bit $1$, and $B$ containing the vertices with $t$-th bit $0$.  In this way, if vertices $i$ and $j$ disagree at the $t$-th bit, then the edge $ij$ belongs to the $t$-th bipartite graph (and if $i \neq j$, then they disagree at some bit).

  (We may delete edges that appear in multiple bipartite graphs.  It doesn't change anything.)
- Proof that $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ bipartite graphs is necessary.

  If $(A_t \cup B_t)_{t=1}^k$ is the sequence of vertex bipartitions of the bipartite subgraphs that cover $K_n$, then for each vertex $v$ we assign it a non-negative integer label with $t$-th bit equal to $1$ is $v$ belongs to $A_t$ and $0$ if $v$ belongs to $B_t$.  There are $\leq 2^k$ such labels.

  For an edge $ij$ to be covered, there must be some $t$ for which $i \in A_t$ and $j \in B_t$, or $i \in B_t$ and $j \in A_t$.  Consequently, $i$ and $j$ must receive distinct labels.  Thus, to have enough labels, we must have $2^k \geq n$.