# The complete graph $K_n$ can be expressed as the union of $k$ bipartite graphs iff $n≤2^k$

Tags: graph-theory

> The complete graph $K_n$ can be expressed as the union of $k$ bipartite graphs iff $n≤2^k$.

A similar question has been asked. However I believe that question was regarding the proof. I am not asking for a proof and I just want to know how to get $2^k$. Thank you!

link to the related question: [$K_n$ as an union of bipartite graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344024/k-n-as-an-union-of-bipartite-graphs)

Comment: What do you mean "how to get $2^k$"?  Are you asking "where does the number $2^k$ come from?" or "how can I express $K_{2^k}$ as the union of $k$ bipartite graphs?"  If you know that a similar question was asked on this site, then why didn't you link to it?  This question needs more context.

Comment: I am asking where does the number 2^k come from

Comment: The proof might give you insight on where does $2^k$ come from. Link the proof here and maybe we can help you figure that out.

Comment: the proof that i prefer is here at item 4: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103x/2007/solutions8.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the $k$ bipartite graphs, assign every vertex of $K_n$ a red/blue colour that respects the bipartition (there may be more than one such colouring, so just pick one arbitrarily).  This yields a vector of $k$ colours at each vertex.  If $n > 2^k$ then two vertices must have exactly the same $k$-vector of colours.  But then this means there is never an edge between them in any of the $k$ graphs... which means that the graphs fail to cover that edge in $K_n$.

Comment: finally! i think i've got it! thank you! :D